# Are unclickable tags/chips a good practice?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, layout, design-patterns, information-design

Title says it all basically.

I have to show a trip that contains **Title, description and a bunch of random additional info (the tags)**. The issue lays in those tags they should not be clickable and tags looks like the best way to divide the three "types of information" of a trip (second example with just dividers looks a bit messier).

Now the issue: are unclickable tags a thing in the UX world or is it going to be the worst decision of my life?

P.s: Maybe there's an easy and obvious fix to this that you do see, but I don't ?

[image: Kind of good]

[image: Not too good]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second approach.

Tags are normally clickable and often act as filters or search query of some sort. 
In your case:

- Time looks like you can 'schedule' something;
- Weights look like there's a list of your heath&fitness trips in London;
- Pin looks like a map-opener;
- Phone looks like you can click and call directly; and
- Person looks like you can open Alexandra's profile.

Your simpler approach, with text and dividers (plus your icons) is actually cleaner and less confusion of what is clickable (the blue button) and what isn't.

Hope this helps.

Comment: agree that the simpler approach is much better! and it looks cleaner!

Answer (score 5):

Go for the Simpler one.

[image]

It is the shape of the tags that is the actual problem. They make it look like buttons. Moreover, they are also presented together which creates the illusion

This refers to the perceived and actual properties of the thing, primarily those fundamental properties that determine just how the thing could possibly be used or in short **AFFORDANCE**. We should get rid of [Affordance](https://uxplanet.org/ux-design-glossary-how-to-use-affordances-in-user-interfaces-393c8e9686e4) here.

I think the second one where you placed almost evenly-spaced sections with equal margins do not confuse a user.

Comment: I agree with @Supra, I actually think the 2nd option you have is the cleaner one, i don't think it's messy.

Comment: Thanks @Peter,  that's a better way to present them as non-clickable items

Comment: Please @Dennis let us know your approach

Comment: @Supra went with the 2nd approach. Maybe later I'll find a way to make it look a bit better, but until then having non-confusing elements is the way to go. Thanks.